# Correct way to handle dataset dependencies in package development?

Tags: r, dataset, dependencies, package

I'm attempting to build a package that depends on some data from another package.  *Writing R Extensions* says to avoid the use of `require` in package functions.  I may not use all the tables in the `Lahman` package, and am currently importing them this way...

```
team.batting <- function(year, league, playoffs = FALSE)
{
    ...
    Batting <- Lahman::Batting
    Teams <- Lahman::Teams 

    ## calculations, subsets, etc. 
    ...
}
```

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct way to call an exported data set in a package function? And is the end user required to have the package installed for this to work?

Also, I'm not really clear on what a *development* version is, as compared to an installed version. If anyone could shed some light, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: If you're using the data set why do you care if it's a dependency? It needs to get loaded for you to use it...

Comment: Yeah, but I already have it. It's not a fast download, that's why it concerns me a little.

Comment: If you want to use the data in the package then the user needs the package installed.

Comment: Although if you only need some of the data included in the package you could possibly just grab those datasets and include them directly as datasets in your package.  If you provide the appropriate citations this would be fine I believe.  But the Lahman package isn't *sooo* big that it would be unreasonable to have users download it.

Comment: This comment no longer applies because of changes to devtools.

Comment: Thanks.  I've removed that quote and link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I've determined the the correct way to do this is to include the directive

```
import(Lahman)
```

in the NAMESPACE file of my package (or possibly `importFrom(Lahman, table name)` depending on how many tables are used).   After doing this, the `::` calls can be removed.

```
team.batting <- function(year, league, playoffs = FALSE)
{
    ...
    bat <- Batting
    tms <- Teams 

    ## calculations, subsets, etc. 
    ...
}
```